# MAT_DIALOG_DATA: Error: inject() must be called from an injection context Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've made a basic modal dialog from the tutorials and am a bit stuck, loading my project serves me this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:728)
```

I'm not sure why the error message says lowercase-i inject() instead of capital-I @Inject, which i am invoking in the constructor

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'term-component',
  templateUrl: './term.component.html'
})
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogModule],
  providers: [{
    provide: MatDialog, useValue: {}
  }]
})

export class TermDialog implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private modalData: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TermDialog>
  ) {
    console.log(this.modalData);
  }

  ngOnInit() { alert(''); }

  actionFunction() {
    this.closeModal();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

all the similar help topics say to ensure that I am using capital-I @Inject instead of inject, which I am doing. However, i did see one suggestion to import Inject from '@angular/core/testing' instead of '@angular/core', which I do not think is possible?

Any help would be appreciated, I've never gotten stuck so many times on a Hello World project before.

NEW:

okay so I think I have fulfilled all 5 requirements but I am still seeing the same error.
this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AmplifyAngularModule, AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';

import { TermComponent } from './term.component';
import { TermDialog } from './term-dialog.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    TermComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    TermDialog
  ],
  imports: [
    AmplifyAngularModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'term', component: TermComponent },
      { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
    ])
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    TermDialog
  ],
  providers: [
    AmplifyService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my term.component file that is supposed to launch the term-dialog

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TermService } from '../../services/term.service';
import { TermDialog } from './term-dialog.component';
import { compileNgModule } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'term-component',
  templateUrl: './term.component.html'
})
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDialogModule],
  providers: [{ provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} 
  }]
})
export class TermComponent {
  clicked: boolean;
  success: boolean;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private termService: TermService) {

    this.clicked = false;
  }

  openAddNewTermDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.height = "350px";
    dialogConfig.width = "600px";
    dialogConfig.data = {
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TermDialog, dialogConfig);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('closed dialog');
      this.success = result;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the NgModule from both the component files and also don't forget to remove all the imports that are related to it (just to save you some space - not critical though)

Comment: As I see that you are not passing any data, you can remove declaring Inject in the TermDialog as well. It's not mandatory.

Comment: so these are just cosmetic changes, right? How do I fix the "Inject from Injection Context" problem?

Comment: I think it has got something to with the selector and templateURL in the TermDialog component. Let me confirm what changes are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so turns out the answer was just to not use MatDialogs at all, and just simply inject the TermDialogComponent html into the basic modal dialog using the TermDialogComponent's selector tag

So i added html for a modal dialog into my term.component.html and simply pasted in

```
<term-dialog-component></term-dialog-component>
```

and everything worked as intended with no fuss, added modules/librarys whatsoever. I may never know why I couldn't get a basic modal MatDialog to work properly, but I've made my peace with that. My advice for anyone with this same problem is to not use MatDialogs, it isn't worth it and also the weird tab animations look funny anyway.

thanks to everyone for their responses and time

Answer (score 2):

For a `mat-dialog` to work as expected, we have to fulfill the below points.

**# 1** Declare the `dialog` component in it's corresponding `module`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatDialogModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  entryComponents: [
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**# 2** Invoke the `mat-dialog` with the variable that is of type `MatDialog` from the parent component.

```
public dialog: MatDialog
```

**# 3** Declare `dialogRef` on the dialog component to access it's methods.

```
@Component({/* ... */})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialog>) { }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close('Pizza!');
  }
}
```

**# 4** Declare `@Inject` on the dialog component if you want to pass some data from the parent component to the dialog component.

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
})
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

**# 5** Declare the component as [entryComponents](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-) in the `module` definition.

Ref - https://medium.com/@ppm1988/matdialog-not-displaying-properly-b3c4cf19ec4

## **Solution**:

I see that you have taken care of the points 3 & 4. Try fixing other points too.

> You might also want to add `animations` module if you have not already did that.

Ref: [MatDialog not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49414975/2959821)

> Make sure the application is loaded with `css` theme.

Ref: [Angular Material's Dialog won't display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909307/angular-materials-dialog-wont-display-correctly)

Comment: okay so I think I have fulfilled all 5 requirements (i added the dialogcomponent to the entryComponents array) but I am still seeing the same error. Edited the original to include my term.component class and my app.module file

Comment: @BrandonMiller Everything looks fine except the NgModule on both the components. You are anyways importing the packagesin your app.module, so you can remove that section from both the components.

Comment: I am still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Let me run it in my end. Check back in 30 mins.

Comment: There is no separate HTML for TermDialog. It is referring to the TermComponent's template and selector..

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate HTML for TermDialog. It is referring to the TermComponent's template and selector.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-check?embed=1&file=src/app/term-dialog.component.ts)

> I have commented out some statements in the demo code which were irrelevant to the solution.

**Animations**
Also add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the app.module

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  // ...
})
```

Ref: [MatDialog not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414975/matdialog-not-showing)

**Theme**
I guess you have taken care of the material theme as well.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ref: 
[Angular Material's Dialog won't display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909307/angular-materials-dialog-wont-display-correctly)